# Cant write to log file in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a web service in .Net 4.0.  I'm deploying said web service to two IIS servers each running IIS 7.5  Both servers are setup to us the Network Service account.  The code is deployed to a physical disk on the servers.  It attempts to write to a log file also on a local physical disk.  The Network System user has full control permissions on the local directory.  When the service starts, first thing it does is write an entry to the log file.  This works fine on server A, but not on server B.

Can anyone give me a suggestion on where I might look for something that is actively denying file IO on IIS server?

The specific error message is Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Data\Logs\CDelivery.log'.  I can assure you the file is in fact present, and this works just fine on server A.

P.S.  I also tried this solution, but the IE Enhanced Security Configuration is already set to "OFF" for both Admins and Users [IIS 7.5 App Pool write permissions denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377968/iis-7-5-app-pool-write-permissions-denied)

Comment: Are you sure that is the right path on the other server? Might it be another drive letter?

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the code that writes to the file?

Comment: try Directory.Exists("D:\") and Directory.Exists("D:\Data") and post the output

Comment: If you have physical or Remote Desktop access to the server, run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), filtering by the name of the log file, and see what error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  My code to writetolog is in a static class and I was accessing resources before locking them properly.  Since the writetolog function is my generic error handler (among other things) the unhandled exception within it was causing w3pw.exe (and kernalbase.dll) to blow up.

Had to do a good bit of digging to find it because "Can't find file x" was not actually the problem at all.  Terrible error message.